# Swift tamaño dinámico de fuente en textView

Tags: swift, xcode, textview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en **Xcode** en el cual tengo texto en un TextView, con constrains realizo el ajuste al tamaño dependiendo de las dimensiones del dispositivo.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que **el TextView se ajusta pero el texto se pierde** ya que cuando se hace más pequeño el TextView, el texto no se ajusta de tamaño.

¿Hay alguna forma de definir un tamaño dinámico de la fuente en el textView?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza en el controlador de la vista (ViewController), en viewDidLoad():

```
let tamaño = view.frame.width
let variable1 = x1
let variable2 = x2

switch tamaño {
  case tamaño1:
    textview.font = UIFont(name: textview.font.fontName, size: variable1)
  default:
    textview.font = UIFont(name: textview.font.fontName, size: variable2)
}
```

Sustituye x1 y x2 por los tamaños que quieras poner al texto, y añade tantos casos como necesites. Cambia width por height para tener en cuenta la altura de la vista. Y declara textview con un outlet del Text View a controlar. Espero haberte ayudado. Ante cualquier duda pregunta.

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha ayudado. :D

Answer (score 1):

Se puede cambiar el tamaño del texto cada que el `textView` cambie su tamaño. Para lograr eso se puede utilizar la función `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` del `viewController` que contenga nuestro `textView`.

En este ejemplo se modifica el tamaño acorde a la altura del `textView`, pero se puede cambiar la lógica y siempre que se redimensionen las subvistas del controlador el texto cambiará:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: textView.bounds.height / 14) // El 14 sólo es un número al azar para reducir el tamaño y no ocupe toda la altura
}
```

---

#### Ejemplo para probar su funcionalidad

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var textView: UITextView!
    private var textViewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute : NSLayoutConstraint]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        addTextView()
    }
    
    // Inicializa y configura el `textView`
    func addTextView() {
        textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        view.addSubview(textView)
        
        // Constraints
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textViewConstraints = [
            .top      : textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            .leading  : textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            .trailing : textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            .bottom   : textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(Array(textViewConstraints.values))
    }
    
    // Redimensiona el tamaño del `textView` dependiendo de donde se mueva el dedo
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        if let point = touches.first?.location(in: view) {
            textViewConstraints[.trailing]?.constant = point.x - UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            textViewConstraints[.bottom]?.constant = point.y - UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        }
    }
    
    // Modifica el tamaño del texto dinámicamente
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: textView.bounds.height / 14)
    }

}
```